# WSO2esb-4.8.1 issue with GUI for viewing Logs

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2esb-4.8.1.

We want to use the WSO2 GUI to view the tenant specific log. But we are getting the following message always when we navigate to Monitor--> Application Logs.

The log must be configured to use the org.wso2.carbon.logging.core.util.MemoryAppender to view entries on the admin console

I found that in the log4j.properties, the following is used

> log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appender.CarbonMemoryAppender

I changed this to

> log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY=org.wso2.carbon.logging.core.util.MemoryAppender

The issue remains though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you install WSO2 4.8.1, Esb, it installs the Logging Management 4.2.1
With this, the logs are visible in the GUI. It works as expected. 
But later, if you install any other feature , that includes a higher version of logging management (eg:- in our case, we installed data services 3.1.1 that includes logging management feature 4.2.2), the GUI stops working.

All I did was unchecking the logging feature in data services 3.1.1 when installing data services. This way, the logging feature did not get upgraded, but the rest of the data services did.